# Cannot reference two projects in the same solution

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on one project, where I have Domain and UI projects. I have searched a while, but cannot find proper answer to why I cannot reference one class from one project to another.
Please advice me what am I supposed to do if I start the project from the beginning and will not to add references.
Could you provide with steps. I would be enormously grateful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: YOu mean you were unable to find a tutorial how to reference a project? For example in google "visual studio add project reference" - is that SOO hard?

Comment: I keep getting an error such as The type and namespaces name could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference)

Comment: The error message is telling you that you haven't got the assembly reference to the assembly that defines the type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets say you have Project A.
In that project you would have some filename, let's say `ClassA.cs`

In that file you would have a `class ClassA` which would be inside a namespace `ProjectANamespace`.

Now let's say you want to access `ClassA` in a different project `Project B` in class `classB`.

So at the top of the `ClassB` file put in the line:
`using ProjectANamespace`. After that in ClassB you can use ClassA.

This is very very layman explanation: Please Google "**Adding Namespaces in C#**"